# What does this question means by vertical slice?

Tags: calculus

Construct and evaluate the definite integral representing the area of the region described using "vertical slices"

They intersect between x = 0 and 3

The area is enclosed by $y=x^2$ and $y=3x$ the area is easy enough to find....
$$\int_{0}^{3} 3x - \int_{0}^{3} x^2$$

But it wants vertical slices does this mean i have to use...
$\sqrt{y}=x$ and $\frac{1}{3}y=x$

$$\sqrt{y}=\frac{y}{9} $$ $$(y-\frac{y^2}{9})=0$$ 
$$ \frac{1}{9}y(9-y)=0$$

Hence they intersect at y= 0 and y = 9

$$\int_{0}^{9} 3x - \int_{0}^{9} \frac{1}{3}y$$

Comment: Your integral $\int_0^3 (3x-x^2)\,dx$ uses vertical slices.

Answer (score 1):

Remember the definition of a definite integral $$\int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x =\lim_{n\to \infty} \sum_{i=1}^n f(x_i) \, \Delta x$$

You are using vertical slices already(adding infinitely small ones) by using $\int_0^3(3x-x^2) \mathrm{d}x$. Here's a gif to help you understand it better.

[image]